# How to get button to float over kendo widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, kendo-ui

[image]I have a "dashboard" with 9 tiles. Each tile can contain a custom Kendo widget. I would like to be able to edit each widget individually so I placed an edit icon in the top right

```
.right-side
  .dashboard-button.alt
    .fa.fa-pencil
```

and floated it

```
.right-side{
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
```

The **widget** gets inserted one of the tiles. The widget has an attribute to  **fill its parent height** (one of the 9 tiles on the dashboard)

```
.custom-widget{data: {'custom-chart-data' => widget.widget_data, 'url' => 'test', 'fill-parent-height' => 'true', 'widget-options' => widget.options_data }}
```

The problem is that whenever this "edit button" is on one of the tiles it the widget does not include it when calculating parent height and leaves the tiles with a scroll bar. (it is only about 12px)

[image]

I can not figure out how to render the widget and make it know to fill its parent but account for the button that is inside its tile.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the UI so we can see what you have so far?

Comment: I added two shots. You can see my problem in the second one. All the tiles have scroll bars because they have a edit button and widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added more configuration the widget when building it.

```
if widget.data("fill-parent-height")
  summary_chart_options.chartArea = { height: widget.parent().height() - 40 }
widget.kendoChart( summary_chart_options )
```

The **- 40** was not there before. Basically my button is about 40px so that did the trick.